# Strange Looking Cursor on New Pc

Tags: cursor

brand new optiplex 5040 and the mouse cursor looks.. odd. As if it isn't being smoothed at the edges or is running at a lower colour depth? It's most noticeable on the loading wheel. It just looks jagged.

I've tried changing the cursors and back again, and I've updated the graphics drivers.

It's not affecting anything and it's purely visual, but it bugs me that I do not know why this is the case. Everything else looks normal.

There is a picture below but its hard to show properly.

Does anyone have any suggestions?[[image: Picture of Cursor[1]]

[image]

Comment: what type of computer and which version of Windows do you use? Have you tried looking in mouse settings which pointer scheme is selected?

Comment: Yes, changed the scheme here away and back again.Optiplex 5040 as stated, Windows 7. It seems when intel driver is removed, it looks okay and normal when running at lower res, as if the driver is at fault.